# How to trace a failed asynchronous test in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, promise, jestjs

**- UPDATE -**

**The issue has been identified.**

In the actual codebase the assertion is passed to a imported callback, and once the callback executes with a failed test, it raises a promise rejection.

So, this is close to how the test was actually written:

```js
describe( "file system", () => {

  it( "should check if the file exists", async () => {

    call( async () => {

      const received = await fileExists();
      const expected = true;

      expect( received ).toBe( expected );

    });
  });
});
```

and the complex callback is presented in a simpler way to produce the same issue:

```js
export function call( callback) {

  callback();

}
```

---

**- UPDATE -**

**The following code works.**

I picked up a small portion of the code from a large codebase for better visibility. If I run just the following piece of code, it works as expected. I think there's an issue in the actual codebase.

@Flask's recommendation of handling the unhandled promise rejections centrally added a great value to the question.

---

**Consider the following test:**

```js
import fileExists, { call } from "./exists";

describe( "file system", () => {

  it( "should check if the file exists", async () => {

    const received = await fileExists();
    const expected = true;

    expect( received ).toBe( expected );
  });
});
```

**for the following source:**

```js
import fs, { constants } from "fs";
import { promisify } from "util";

export default async function fileExists() {

  const path    = ".nonexistent";
  const access  = promisify( fs.access );

  try {

    await access( path, constants.F_OK );

  } catch {

    return false;

  }

  return true;

}
```

When `fileExists` <del>rejects</del> returns `false`, an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is received <del>as expected</del>. But this does not help trace the source of the failed test.

For synchronous tests, Jest shows the path to the test (i.e. `file system › should check if the file exists`) which helps trace the source of the failed test.

What is the best way to achieve this for asynchronous tests?

Comment: The problem is specific to fileExists which wasn't shown.

Comment: Added the source. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is not expected here. It's not equivalent to failed test because it doesn't prevent a test to pass if assertions pass. It means that the code was written the wrong way and contains unchained promises.

It can happen only if `await` was omitted in the test:

```
fileExists(); // no await
```

Or `fileExists` function contains loose unhandled promises:

```
fileExists() {
  whatever() // no return
  .then(() => {
    whatever() // no return
  })  // no catch to suppress errors
}
```

It's a good practice to have in `setupFiles`:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', console.error);
```

It provides more useful output than `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and allows to debug the problem based on error stack.

Comment: Please check the source added to the question. Thanks. :-)

Comment: fileExists is ok and shouldn't cause this error, so yes, the problem was `call`. This is where unhandledRejection listener can become handy. Btw, there's promise-enabled access, it doesn't need to be promisified, https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api