# How to efficiently troubleshoot "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" errors?

Tags: node.js, angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am talking about the following error, when testing Angular components or services:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'element' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'componentProvider' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'parent' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at writeChannelMessage (internal/child_process/serialization.js:118:20)
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:779:17)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:677:19)
    at reportSuccess (/home/user/code/my-app/node_modules/jest-runner/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:67:11)
(node:4658) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

These usually happen to me when I forgot to mock an async method on a service that is run during the test. Sometimes it's easy to find which because the component/service is small, but other times it's hard because there are so many places where this could happen.

How can I efficiently troubleshoot this class of errors and find out what is causing it? The trace is not useful and tells me nothing at all about where to look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366001/how-to-trace-a-failed-asynchronous-test-in-jest

Comment: unhandledRejection listener may be enough. *but other times it's hard because there are so many places where this could happen* - that you don't mock enough may be the real problem, mock anything but tested unit. Isolated unit tests are good for isolating the issues.

Comment: @EstusFlask: the solution in that question is to add `process.on('unhandledRejection', console.error);` to the jestSetup file. Having that setting is what yields the message and trace in my question.