# Ignore a rejected fire-and-forget promise in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, jestjs

My store's `processAction()` function calls a private async function in a fire-and-forget manner which then does a fetch.  `processAction()` itself does not handle any error handling, and--in the browser--if the fetch fails, an external library handles any and all uncaught promise rejections.

So, if I mock my fetch to reject, the private function--the effects of which I am testing--will reject.  Since I don't have a reference to the promise created by my async function call, I have no way of catching the rejection within the test, but the test fails because there was an unhandled rejection.

How can I tell jest to be okay with this short of calling the private function itself rather than just triggering the action that calls it?

**actions.ts**

```ts
const actions = {
  doTheThing() {
    dispatch({ type: 'DO_THE_THING' });
  },
};

export default actions;
```

**store.ts**

```ts
import fetch from './fetch';

class Store {
  isFetching = false;

  // ...

  processAction({ type, payload }: { type: string, payload: any }) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'DO_THE_THING':
        this.fetchTheThing();
        break;
    }
  }

  private async fetchTheThing() {
    try {
      this.isFetching = true;
      const result = await fetch(myUrl);
      // ...
    } finally {
      this.isFetching = false;
    }
  }
}

export default new Store();
```

**__mocks__/fetch.ts**

```ts
let val: any;
interface fetch {
  __setVal(value: any): void;
}

export default async function fetch() {
  return val;
}

fetch.__setVal = function(value: any) {
  val = value;
};
```

**store.test.ts**

```ts
import actions from './actions';
import store from './store';

const fetch = (require('./fetch') as import('./__mocks__/fetch')).default;
jest.mock('./fetch');

test('it sets/unsets isFetching on failure', async () => {
  let rej: () => void;
  fetch.__setVal(new Promise((_, reject) => rej = reject));
  expect(store.isFetching).toBe(false);

  Actions.doTheThing();
  await Promise.sleep(); // helper function
  expect(store.isFetching).toBe(true);

  rej(); // <---- test fails here
  await Promise.sleep();
  expect(store.isFetching).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: Mock the super duper global exception handling API that captures the exception - then use that mock the way you do in your application. That's the proper way. Testing your code in a fashion that does not replicate your deployed environment is a waste of time and does not make a valid test.

Comment: This project is loaded into a shell that I don't control.  The shell is the one that handles the super-duper exception handling.

Comment: Then mock the shell

Comment: That is *wayyyy* out of the scope of the feature I've been assigned.  And regardless, I don't even know how it handles promises at the global level, so I don't know how I would mock that.  Clearly jest itself handles unhandled promises.  Is there no way to tell jest to keep going on rejected promises?

Comment: not really, you'll end up just swallowing it.

Comment: That's the whole point.  I *want* it to be swallowed and to test the state of the store afterward.

Comment: `try { reject(); } catch(err) { //swallow } finally { await Promise.sleep(); expect(...);`

Comment: I already tried it.  It didn't work.  The error isn't thrown within the test.  It's thrown within the private async function.

Comment: Ah...didn't see it. Then you're screwed. Sorry. Can't stimulate private methods. This is a future bug that you clearly see is a code smell.

Comment: Probably the best course of action would be to capture the exception within the private method to swallow it there, while then emitting a custom exception from the private method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225547/discussion-between-dx-over-dt-and-randy-casburn).

Comment: A thing like "rejected fire-and-forget promise" shouldn't ever happen. That it was discovered when writing a test is good. So fix it.

Comment: @EstusFlask In production, it *is* handled by the shell, which is outside the scope of this project.  I don't know how it does it, just that it does.  In the case that fetch fails, I want the shell to handle it, so I do *not* want to handle it in the function itself.

Comment: What you talk about is handling an unexpected exception. It should exist but that you don't handle an error where you expect it, and request error is pretty much expected. Any way, I listed possible options to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My function calls a private async function in a fire-and-forget manner, and does not add any error handling.

Don't do that.

> An external library handles any and all uncaught promise rejections. In production, I want the shell to handle it, so I do not want to handle it in the function itself.

Don't rely on this external library.

You should have your own global error handling function that you use in your function.

In production, have that error handling function simply rethrow the exception so that it gets picked up by the environment, or better, do call the shell error handling function directly if possible.

In the tests, you can mock out your own global handler, and assert that it is called with the expected arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`processAction` is synchronous and unaware of promises and this results in a dangling promise. Dangling promises should never reject because this results in unhandled rejection, which is a kind of exception. This may cause an application to crash depending on the environment. Even if exceptions are handled globally, this shouldn't be an reason to not handle errors where they are expected.

A correct way to do this is to suppress a rejection explicitly either in `fetchTheThing` where it occurs:

```
  private async fetchTheThing() {
    try {
      ... 
    } catch {} finally {
      this.isFetching = false;
    }
  }
```

Or in this case, it's more like `processAction` that results in dangling promise:

```
this.fetchTheThing().catch(() => {});
```

Otherwise unhandled rejection event is dispatched.

Without that, it could be tested by listening for the event:

```
  ...
  let onRej = jest.fn();
  process.once('unhandledRejection', onRej);
  rej();
  await Promise.sleep();
  expect(onRej).toBeCalled();
  expect(store.isFetching).toBe(false);
```

This won't work as intended if there's already another `unhandledRejection` listener, which [can be expected in a good Jest setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64366742/3731501). If this is the case, the only workaround that won't affect other tests is to reset them before the test and re-add afterwards:

```
let listeners;

beforeEach(() => {
  listeners = process.rawListeners('unhandledRejection');
  process.removeAllListeners('unhandledRejection');
});

afterEach(() => {
  (typeof listeners === 'function' ? [listeners] : listeners).forEach(listener => {
    process.on('unhandledRejection', listener);
  });
})
```

This isn't recommended and should be used at own risk because this indicates a deeper problem with error handling that is not generally acceptable in properly designed JavaScript application.

Comment: I would honestly not mention the `"unhandledRejection"` hook here and stick to the `.catch(() => {})` approach though as you point out this indicates a bigger design problem with the code since `DO_THE_THING` can fail and no one knows. Good answer.